# Custom designing a simple android button

Tags: android, android-button

### Custom designing a Button

---

*I Have a simple button*

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### How can i custom design this button as below

[image]

**Specification i am trying to do::**

- A background black color
- The text of the button to be at the **bottom** of the button as in the
  figure

**Any Ideas**

Comment: you can also change gravity for above as the text is the content for the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulkit is correct about using gravity to position the text. Specifically, you probably want:

```
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
```

For the black background, you can use the background xml attribute:

```
    android:background="@drawable/btn_black"
```

Of course, you'll need to provide a png named btn_black.png in your drawable folder.

If you want the button to look like it's pressed, you need to have different drawables for each state (pressed, normal, focused, etc). You would need to set the buttons background to an xml file describing the states that looks something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
      <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
      <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_black_normal"/> 
      <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false"
            android:drawable="@drawable/btn_black_pressed" />
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_black_normal"/> 
    </selector>
```

Comment: optionally, android:background="@color/black" would work too. But you should make the color in your values folder.